# Access web api using AAD from Azure Function without using secret keys

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm working on Azure Cosmos DB Feed changer Function. My requirement is in the feed changer function I need to access Web API using AAD authentication.

How should I configure the connection between the Azure Function and Web API using AAD so that the azure function can send the change feed to Web API?
How can I call the Web API in the function code?

Thank You,
Dheeraj

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, I suggest you using MSI(Managed Service Identity) in your azure function app.

You could create an identity here.

[image]

Then search the identity in AAD Enterprise Application list,you could find the permissions of it.

[image]

Then please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity#obtaining-tokens-for-azure-resources) to obtain the access token and call your web api  which is using AAD authentication with that token.

In addition, you could store the secret in Azure Key Vault and get the access token from AKV to call your web api. It support you to manage multiply permissions.

More details ,please refer to this link:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2018/06/13/using-managed-service-identity-msi-with-and-azure-app-service-or-an-azure-function/

Comment: Thanks @JayGong  for quick response. <br/>
I don't want to use Azure Key Vault to store the Web Api key and make a call. Can we make a call without adding any tokens or access key in headers and check the authentication from active directory in Web Api code whether the function have access to the Web API.<br/><br/>

Or there is any other way to configure that function have access to web api directly.